# ionic 3 mobile app video auto play and pause on scroll like facebook videos

Tags: html, css, ionic3

> I want to autoplay the video when it comes in the viewport and should stop playing the video when it goes out of the viewport with ionic 3, can anyone please suggest how to do that?

Comment: What you had tried?

Comment: I didn't find any reference for the task which I can use with my ionic 3 app. thanks for your quick response. I'll try this example. :)

Comment: Chechout my answer

Comment: sorry for  not mentioning the platform, actually I want this functionality in my android app. the functionality should be like tik tok or facebook as we scroll up or down and the video which is currently in the middle of the screen starts to play

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var trackerOffset = $('.tracker').offset().top; // offset in document
  var trackerPosition = trackerOffset - $(window).scrollTop(); // offset in viewport
  $('.debug-status').html('video status: ' + checkTrackerPos(trackerPosition));
}).trigger('scroll');

function checkTrackerPos(trackerPosition){
  var triggerTop = $('.trigger-top').position();
  var triggerBottom = $('.trigger-bottom').position();
  if (trackerPosition >= triggerTop.top && trackerPosition <= triggerBottom.top ) {
    return 'playing!';
  }
  return 'paused';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}
.debug {
  font-size:20px;
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:30vw;
  margin-left:-15vw;
  margin-top:-35px;
  padding:15px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
.viewport {
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:200vh;
  border:2px dashed red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column
}
/* Position these two as you please */
.trigger-top,
.trigger-bottom {
  width:100%;
  text-indent:-50%;
  position:fixed;
  top:25%;
  border-top:1px dotted #000;
}
.trigger-bottom {
  top:auto;
  bottom:25%;
}
.video-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  color:blue;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.video-wrapper .tracker {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  padding:1px; /* these 3 attributes are here just for the show */
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
  line-height:1px;
  text-indent:5px; /* again, just for the show */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="debug">
    <div class="debug-trigger"></div>
    <div class="debug-pos"></div>
    <div class="debug-status"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-top">top trigger</div>
  <div class="trigger-bottom">bottom trigger</div>
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    video
    <div class="tracker">tracker</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479802/10971575

Answer (score 0):

Could just call a JS -function when you scroll.

```
<div onscroll="myFunction()">
```

And the JS-function would roughly look like this:

```
if (end of viewport > document.body.scrollTop > start of viewpoint || end of viewport > document.documentElement.scrollTop > start of viewpoint) {
    vid.play();
  }else{vid.pause();}
```